# Can I migrate the OCI vm to GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, migration, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I want to know the way how to migrate the VM launched on OCI to GCP.

I just studying the cloud environment, especially cloud migration.
I have a one server at OCI and that OS is centos.
So I am trying to migrate it to GCP environment, I can not find the way to migrate it from OCI to GCP in the following documents.
documnets: https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.11/how-to/prepare-vms-servers/preparing-linux-vms

Please tell me how to find the way to migrate the server from OCI.
If there is no way to do it, tell me the reason why I can't

Comment: I understand OCI and GCP well. I do not recommend migrating VMs from one cloud to another. The reason is that each cloud installs its own systems-level software to interact with its cloud management systems. Back up the applications and restore them to a new instance. If you want portability between cloud vendors, build and deploy containers.

Comment: But I want to know the availability of migration. If you go to the GCP migration document  I attached, There are no section of OCI